# How to verify if an email was received and read

Tags: email, email-server, sendmail, mx-record, email-bounces

I accidentally sent an email to a wrong email address. The owner told me that he didn't receive my email because there were no email servers configured for that domain. However when I did MX lookup, I found two mail servers for that domain, and several mail server testing tools also show that those two servers can receive incoming emails for that email address. In addition, that email never bounced back. Do these facts indicate that the owner was lying to me? How can I verify whether my email was received and read by him?

Comment: Check your mail server log.

Comment: How exactly can I do that?

Comment: You didn't specify anything about your mail server!

Answer (score 1):

> Do these facts indicate that the owner was lying to me?

No. The fact that an MX record exists for the domain and a that successful email address test do not confirm that the email was in fact delivered successfully.

How can I verify whether my email was received and read by him?

Unless you requested a delivery receipt and a read receipt and received a positive confirmation of both, you can't verify that your email was received and read.

Comment: I don't understand. Why can you say "the fact that an MX record exists for the domain and that a successful email address test does not confirm that the email was in fact delivered successfully"? Could you please explain?

Comment: The MX record and email test only confirm that an MX record exists and that a mailbox appears to exist. They don't confirm that an email sent to the email address is actually delivered or will actually be delivered. an email sent to the address may not reach the mailbox for a litany of reasons. Block lists, spam filters, etc. may prevent delivery to the actual mailbox.